# Data Warehouse - DB2 to SQL Server: how and what impacts on ETL?

Tags: sql-server, db2, migration, data-warehouse, informatica

I'm working towards migrating an IBM DB2 database to SQL Server, however the DB2 database sits in a Data Warehouse environment.

As I am very new to Data Warehousing, DB2 and DB Migration between different types of databases, I would like to ask about how to best approach this and understand what components are involved (listing or linking elsewhere is fine - happy to read a bunch of things or learn something new).

The context:

- The ETL tool in use, and to be kept in use, is Informatica
- The only application that queries the DB is Cognos
- There are 4 DB2 DBs in use on 2 (non-windows) hosts, one of these is 'H1' which has a 'DB2-DW-PROD' DB used as part of the Data Warehouse
- I am interested in migrating the 'DB2-DW-PROD' DB to some space I have on an existing (Windows) SQL Server host, 'H2' under the name 'SQL-DW-PROD'. This host currently has several DBs on it for other purposes (in one instance) and can have SSRS/SSIS or other services/resources installed or configured if needed.
- I would like to clean up the poorly maintained DB a little bit during the migration, if possible, based off what has not been used/updated in the past couple of years.

What I would like to know, directly or indirectly:

- Should I create a new instance on H2 or is a single new database enough?
- Does the new instance/DB need particular resources? If so, where from?
- Should I use a particular Microsoft tool or use some type of import/export to get the data I need? (Is Informatica involved in this process?)
- Someone mentioned 'metadata tables' for Informatica and/or Cognos, should I be wary of something?
- Another mentioned maintaining sequence values -How is this best achieved; is it needed?
- Any changes on the Informatica side are not my personal concern but the work of another, as such, Is there anything I should provide this person (apart from the address of the new db)?

Comment: This is not a single programming-related problem and should be discussed on the dba site.

Comment: I'm new to this, would you have a link I can use?

Comment: EDIT: I've posted it here, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173295/data-warehouse-db2-to-sql-server-how-what-impacts-on-etl
please let me know if this site is the right one !!

Comment: The excellant [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/forrards-group-database-blog/2015/08/03/single-instance-vs-multiple-instances-of-sql-server-on-a-server/) has a blog post on multiple instances vs multiple dbs.  My advise is; prototype and test everything.  As you are new to this, better to make your mistakes on a smaller test db.  Avoid the tidy up until post migration.  Checking the data is the same before/after a move is hard enough.  If it changes during transfer it's much, much harder.

Comment: This is a very broad question, and would likely close on any Stack Exchange site. You could try Reddit, where design/broad questions might be OK, depending on the rules of the sub-room you choose.

Comment: thanks guys really appreciate it :)